# can't connect to RabbitMQ from a celery worker - 403 ACCESS_REFUSED - flask

Tags: python, docker, rabbitmq, celery

I have a Flask application, a Celery worker and a RabbitMQ queue running in a docker container.
Flask and Celery worker are running locally in my IDE.

I set up RabbitMQ using docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    hostname: rabbitmq
    image: 'rabbitmq:latest'
    ports:
      - '4369:4369'
      - '5672:5672'
      - '5671:5671'
      - '15672:15672'
      - '25672:25672'
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=myuser
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypassword
    expose:
      - 5671
      - 4369
      - 5672
```

and I'm passing "amqp://myuser:mypassword@127.0.0.1:5672//" as celery_broker_url to Celery.

The RabbitMQ is up and said "started TCP listener on [::]:5672", but when I'm trying to run my worker, it fails with an exception

> amqp.exceptions.AccessRefused: (0, 0): (403) ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.

Rabbit is writing logs to standard output and there is no single new line appearing when I'm trying to boot my worker. So it looks like the rabbit doesnt get the connection try from my worker? but why is it 403 then, not 404 or 500 or whatever?

i'll appreciate any ideas on why could this happen and how to resolve the issue.

Comment: You are writing: "a Celery worker and a RabbitMQ queue running in a docker container. Flask and Celery worker are running locally in my IDE.", so the question do you run Celery in docker or locally?

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev celery and flask are running locally in IDE, and RabbitMQ is running in Docker.